# docker-compose: cannot add local module to project, canno find package.json file

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have two projects, let's say, projectA and projectB.  The folder heirarchy looks like the following:

```
projects
    - banking
        - accounts
           - projectA
        - loans
           - projectB
```

I added projectA to projectB as a local module using npm install and this worked as I was able to access the code.  However, when I tried to push projectB to the docker server using docker-compose running through WebStorm I am receiving an error:

npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL

npm ERR! Could not install from "../../accounts/projectA" as it does not contain a package.json file.

This is strange as this folder definitely contains a package.json file.  Also, it seems to fail when it tries to run this command line

RUN cd /home/parent && npm install --production

1. What would block it from seeing the package.json file, if it is there?
2. What would I need to do to make this work as local modules definitely make sense in this case but are not playing well with docker?

Answer (score 1):

when you execute a docker build you send all the current directory to docker (its called context). then it starts building things.

it means that docker only has access to a particular folder (usually the current folder)

../ is therefore out of it

Comment: What could be done as a solution to this issue considering that accessing local modules seems like it would be a common necessity?

Comment: i dont see a clean solution using local modules. That's why i dont use them. You could create a private/public module on npm, then docker will be able to npm install it from whatever context. Or you can put your dockerfile in the parent folder. that way he will have access to both subfolders.

Comment: Would it help if I made a symbolic link to projectB from projectA?  Then, theoretically, they would be in the same folder.

Comment: docker build sends context (files). then execute it. I dont think that he reads symlinks. But hard link should work.

Comment: How would I hard link if the contents of the entire project are needed?